# How to allow user to only submit an infopath form without read/write access?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, sharepoint-workflow

I have a infopath form already built, how do I achieve the following?

- user is able to access the form via infopath form web part.
- user is able to fill out the form and submit via the web part.
- user cannot go to Site Contents to even view the result, neither their own, nor others'
- user cannot view/edit any results. Submit data only.

Is this possible in SharePoint 2013? So far the closest I could get to is use custom permission level to allow user to only view but not edit item. But I don't want them to even view the result of others. They should only see the form via the web part and submit data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom Event receiver on item added event. once the item added just break the permission inheritance and assign the permission for admin only.

So now user can submit the data but they can't able to see that

Comment: Could you elaborate on this slightly? Where do I create a Custom Event receiver? is that in SharePoint Designer or InfoPath, or?  Thanks!

Comment: Event receiver you need to create using Visual studio as a farm solution

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to submit the form data to another site by web services.